# Merging multiple Firebase Snapshot Data in the same tableView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

In my App I want to show a feed which generates a tableView depending on which groups the user subscribed. In the background two Firebase request are done and then converted to a tableView.
My Code shows the content correct. But there are two issues. The order is wrong. It should be 4->3->2->1 (based on timestamp) and right now it is random. Also if I click on a comment the didSeleceRowAt works totally wrong.
How can I manage to put the result in the same tableView correctly?

```
func datenBankAbfrage() {

    ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/h77e24d95a5479ed7588")
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userTime").queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(
        DataEventType.value,
        with: { (snapshot) in

            self.ref = Database.database().reference().child(
                "placeID/vh-b83b6e4475e04e3fbaa647d23b")
            self.ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userTime").queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(
                DataEventType.value,
                with: { (snapshot2) in

                    for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        let Object1 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                        let userName = Object1?["userName"]
                        let userGroup = Object1?["userGroup"]
                        let userComment = Object1?["userComment"]
                        let userTime = Object1?["userTime"]
                        let userLikes = Object1?["userLikes"]
                        let commentId = Object1?["commentId"]

                        ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId as! String
                        let video = importComment(
                            userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                            userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! Int,
                            userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String)
                        self.table.insert(video, at: 0)
                        // self.table.append(video)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                    for video in snapshot2.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        let Object2 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                        let userName = Object2?["userName"]
                        let userGroup = Object2?["userGroup"]
                        let userComment = Object2?["userComment"]
                        let userTime = Object2?["userTime"]
                        let userLikes = Object2?["userLikes"]
                        let commentId = Object2?["commentId"]
                        ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId as! String
                        let video2 = importComment(
                            userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                            userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! Int,
                            userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String)
                        self.table.insert(video2, at: 0)
                        // self.table.append(video)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
        })
}
```

```
class importComment {
    var userName: String?
    var userID: String?
    var userGroup: String?
    var userComment: String?
    var userTime: Int?
    var userLikes: Int?
    var commentId: String?

    init(
        userName: String?, userGroup: String?, userComment: String?, userTime: Int?,
        userLikes: Int?, commentId: String?
    ) {
        self.userName = userName
        self.userGroup = userGroup
        self.userComment = userComment
        self.userTime = userTime
        self.userLikes = userLikes
        self.commentId = commentId
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Something maybe unrelated maybe not: Why are you reloading your table inside the loops? It's better to prepare your data arrays first, then reload your table data.

Comment: You are right I should fix that.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Flag the question for moderator attention explaining that you want to self-delete, and request that they cancel your bounty. Then you can self-delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to fetch data in Loops. As you're calling asynchronous functions in a loop, there is no guarantee of order.

You should use `DispatchGroup`. Here is how execution will go:

1. Create a `DispatchGroup` instance.
2. Add `SnapShot-1` Fetch request to the Dispatch group.
3. Now add `SnapShot-2` Fetch request to the Dispatch group.
4. `Notify()` will only be called after both the tasks has been completed. So you should prepare your data there.
5. Reload Table after data preparation.

Here is an example implementation:

```
func datenBankAbfrage() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/h77e24d95a5479ed7588")
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userTime").queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(
        DataEventType.value,
        with: { (snapshot) in
            
            for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let Object1 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                
                let userName = Object1?["userName"]
                let userGroup = Object1?["userGroup"]
                let userComment = Object1?["userComment"]
                let userTime = Object1?["userTime"]
                let userLikes = Object1?["userLikes"]
                let commentId = Object1?["commentId"]
                
                ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId as! String
                let video = importComment(
                    userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                    userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! Int,
                    userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String)
                self.table.append(video)
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    
    
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    self.ref = Database.database().reference().child(
        "placeID/vh-b83b6e4475e04e3fbaa647d23b")
    self.ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userTime").queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(
        DataEventType.value,
        with: { (snapshot2) in
            
            for video in snapshot2.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let Object2 = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let userName = Object2?["userName"]
                let userGroup = Object2?["userGroup"]
                let userComment = Object2?["userComment"]
                let userTime = Object2?["userTime"]
                let userLikes = Object2?["userLikes"]
                let commentId = Object2?["commentId"]
                ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId as! String
                let video2 = importComment(
                    userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String,
                    userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! Int,
                    userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String)
                self.table.append(video)
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
      // This is invoked when all the tasks in the group is completed.
        self.prepareDatasource()
    }
}

func prepareDatasource() {
    self.table.sort(by: { $0.userTime ?? 0 > $1.userTime ?? 1}) // Sorting data
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Tried it and it works except with one bug. If some other user edits his text while my app is open or if I click the like button it crashes and says: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) It crashes on this line:  dispatchGroup.leave()

Comment: This code should work for one-time fetches. I don't know about the specifics of the Firebase API but I assume that `.observe` means that this gets called repeatedly on data changes. This would explain the errors you are seeing. Set a breakpoint e.e. on `dispatchGroup.leave()` to confirm.

Comment: You probably should use `getData()` or `ObserverSingleEvent()` method to get the initial data first with help of `DispatchGroup`. Then you can set the Listeners separately to get changes from database.

Comment: The API is the Firebase API from Google. Observe means the func is always active and if somethings changes it updates the text automatically. Ok and how can I do that?